# Add "My Tags" to the tags page if logged in

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

My idea is to have the “Favorite Tags” for the current user visible on the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular)[s pa](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name)[ges](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new).
They could be placed here:
[image: Location of "Favorite tags"]

They should be in the same format as the tags currently visible.

Comment: Currently, 'Favorite Tags' with 'edit' options are displayed on the right sidebar panel... so do you want that to be removed and replaced with this one instead? or leave it and have additions of this?

Comment: @HackerKarma Keep the sidebar panel.